# Oracle Random Number Generator Stored Procedure without using DBMS_RANDOM

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, random

I don't have access to the DBMS_RANDOM package, so I would like to create my own stored procedure to generate random numbers in Oracle. Does anyone know how I might do that?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I am trying to generate a random row from each state. This is my code:

```
SELECT Z.* FROM ( 
      SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.STATE ORDER BY (
          select to_char(systimestamp,'ff') from dual)) AS ROW_ID 
        FROM   STATE_TABLE A ) Z WHERE Z.ROW_ID=1;
```

It gives me the same rows everytime I run it, but I want it to give me different rows everytime I run it. Help please?

Comment: Contact DBAs, ask them for privs.

Comment: Use the `dbms_crypto` package instead?  Sure, you could look up any number of pseudo-random number generation algorithms and implement one of these in PL/SQL.  Doing so, however, would be rather insane-- if the DBAs don't want to give you access to the `dbms_random` package, I am hard-pressed to imagine why they would want you to build your own solution that is likely to be much less efficient, much less standard, and much less random.

Comment: Maybe your DBA would let you read data from [random.org](https://www.random.org/) ? :/

Comment: Haha unfortunately I don't have privileges to any packages. To try to get access would take very long and we would like to get this asap so we're trying to create it ourselves.

Comment: _"we would like to get this asap so we're trying to create it ourselves."_ This sound kind of contradictory to me. That being said, how strong has to be that pseudo-random number generator ? For what kind of purpose is it ? In many, if not all, cases, writing his own  pseudo-random number generator is a bad idea -- unless you know _exactly_ what your are doing...

Comment: I would like to randomly select a person from each state and randomly select a person by item purchased.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd - http://xkcd.com/221/.  Is this for a real project or a homework assignment?  I am hard-pressed to imagine why you'd want to do this in a real system or how you could possibly justify the computational expense of doing so in a real system.  Compounding the issue by saying that you don't have time to get the actual privileges you need so you want to write your own even less efficient random number generator seems crazy.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to select random rows from the table you can use SAMPLE clause

```
SELECT * FROM mytable SAMPLE(4);
```

This gives you randomly selected 4% of all rows.

Answer (score 3):

If your DBAs refuse to give you access to `dbms_random` (I have experienced this, for security reasons, but arguing enough got an exemption in the end) you could create a Java call:

```
create or replace function my_random return float as
language java name 'java.lang.Math.random() return double';
/

select my_random from dual;

 MY_RANDOM
----------
.411402327
```

And in your query:

```
SELECT Z.* FROM ( 
  SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.STATE ORDER BY my_random) AS ROW_ID 
  FROM   STATE_TABLE A
) Z WHERE Z.ROW_ID=1;
```

Not saying it's ideal but it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can pseudo generate random numbers with

```
select to_char(systimestamp,'ff') from dual;
```

Comment: Hmm thanks! I tried this in my code, but if I run the code again and again, it just gives me the same rows: 

SELECT Z.* FROM
(  SELECT A.*,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.STATE ORDER BY (select to_char(systimestamp,'ff') from dual)) AS ROW_ID
FROM STATE_TABLE A
) Z
WHERE Z.ROW_ID=1;

Comment: @calgrad - You'd have to ensure that the `systimestamp` changes between calls to get a different number of fractional seconds.  That's If you put in in a query, Oracle is only going to call `systimestamp` once so you'd get the same "random number" for every row.  You could create a separate function that internally calls `systimestamp` and add a `dbms_lock.sleep` call to every execution to ensure that you don't just get a bunch of monotonically increasing values.  That would be slow as heck though.