# Generating random numbers in oracle without dbms_rand

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't seem to use DBMSRAND.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_RANDOM TO *schema*;

ORA-01031: insufficient priveleges
```

Not sure why as I'm using the DBadmin schema to grant, but does anyone have a work around for random number generation in oracle sql?

Comment: just connect to `sys as sysdba` or `system` users, and then grant as in the question.

Comment: Just to expand a bit on @BarbarosÖzhan, the error message means exactly what it says.  Instead of looking for some work-around, you should address the actual issue.  The 'insufficient privilege' means the user issuing the GRANT does not have the privilege to issue the GRANT.  I suspect you were connected as the user you wanted to grant it _to_, but allowing that would be a security hole big enough to drive a Mac truck through.

Comment: You **could** use `to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'FF')` as SYSTIMESTAMP has resolution of nanoseconds (depending on your DB server). But for sure, the proper way of doing is: ask your DBA to get `EXECUTE` privileges on DBMS_RANDOM.

Comment: Try this if it helps you till you get the access .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605545/oracle-random-number-generator-stored-procedure-without-using-dbms-random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really desperate you could roll your own, eg here's an LG one

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  package global is
  3    a number := to_number(to_char(systimestamp,'FF'));
  4  end;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  function rand(r in number) return number is
  3
  4    mill  constant  number:=100000000;
  5    ten_thou constant number:=10000;
  6    lg_num  constant  number:=31415821;
  7
  8    v number;
  9    w number;
 10    x number;
 11    y number;
 12    z number;
 13
 14  begin
 15    w:=trunc(global.a/ten_thou);
 16    x:=mod(global.a,ten_thou);
 17    y:=trunc(lg_num/ten_thou);
 18    z:=mod(lg_num,ten_thou);
 19    v := mod((mod(x*y+w*z,ten_thou)*ten_thou+x*z),mill);
 20    global.a:=mod(v+1,mill);
 21    return(trunc((trunc(global.a/ten_thou)*r)/ten_thou));
 22  end;
 23  /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL> select rand(100) from dual;

 RAND(100)
----------
        21

SQL> select rand(100) from dual;

 RAND(100)
----------
        72

SQL> select rand(100) from dual;

 RAND(100)
----------
         1

SQL> select rand(100) from dual;

 RAND(100)
----------
        43
```

but random number generation is a *science* so you should be aware of the all of the limitations and drawbacks of rolling your own.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

So your best bet is to get appropriate access to the appropriate packages.